# TextView side by side in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml

[image: Inside the green box in the image, i have my two textviews. These are the two im trying to fill out one half of the screen each. Hope you understand.]Im trying to place two textviews, with the same size in width, side by side inside a RelativeLayout. In between them i have made a view of 1 dp in width to separate the textview. I have tried wrap_content for both both it wont work. The textviews are called headerText and headerText2 in in id. Please help me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/hunters" />

<!-- <ScrollView -->
<!-- android:layout_width="match_parent" -->
<!-- android:layout_height="0dip" -->
<!-- android:layout_weight="0.7" > -->


<!-- <LinearLayout -->
<!-- android:layout_width="match_parent" -->
<!-- android:layout_height="wrap_content" -->
<!-- android:orientation="vertical" > -->


<!-- <TextView -->
<!-- android:layout_width="match_parent" -->
<!-- android:layout_height="50dp" -->
<!-- android:gravity="center" -->
<!-- android:textSize="16sp" -->
<!-- android:background="@drawable/btntop" -->
<!-- android:text="Tak for dit køb!" -->
<!-- android:textStyle="bold" -->
<!-- android:textColor="#D0703D" /> -->


<!-- <ir.zinutech.android.DenmarkHunters.widgets.ZinuTextView -->
<!-- android:layout_width="match_parent" -->
<!-- android:layout_height="wrap_content" -->
<!-- android:gravity="left" -->
<!-- android:paddingLeft="5dp" -->
<!-- android:textSize="16sp" -->
<!-- android:paddingTop="5dp" -->
<!-- android:text="Jagt Pro er app’en udviklet til dig, der som jæger gerne vil være opdateret på de nyeste jagttider, soltider og schweisshunderegistre m.m., og alt sammen ud fra din position." -->
<!-- android:textColor="#000000" /> -->
<!-- <ir.zinutech.android.DenmarkHunters.widgets.ZinuTextView -->
<!-- android:layout_width="match_parent" -->
<!-- android:layout_height="wrap_content" -->
<!-- android:gravity="left" -->
<!-- android:paddingLeft="5dp" -->
<!-- android:textSize="16sp" -->
<!-- android:paddingTop="5dp" -->
<!-- android:text="Teamet bag Jagt Pro arbejder hele tiden på at vidreudvikle app´en, så vi kan give vores kunder den bedst mulige brugeroplevelse." -->
<!-- android:textColor="#000000" /> -->


<!-- </LinearLayout> -->
<!-- </ScrollView> -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.7" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/headerText"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btntop"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Danmarks\nJægerforbund"
        android:textColor="#D0703D"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" 
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
 <View 
  android:background="#d3d3d3" 
  android:layout_height="50dp" 
  android:layout_width="1dp" 
  android:id="@+id/view" 
  android:layout_above="@+id/feedList" 
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/headerText"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/feedList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerText"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:listSelector="@null"
        >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/loaidingText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Henter Nyheder..."
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/headerText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/view"
        android:background="@drawable/btntop"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" 
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Jægernes\nMagasin"
        android:textColor="#454544"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you still haven't made the problem clear. what is it that you can't get done? or what is the actual result with this code?

Comment: can you pot some graphical explanation?? some example or picture you want..

Comment: Inside the green box in the image. You can see the two listviews. Each of them should fill one half of the screen. Some they have the same size. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the easiest way to go here is to just wrap the two TextViews in a LinearLayout, something like:

```
It seems to me that the easiest way to go here is to just wrap the two TextViews in a LinearLayout, something like:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/hunters" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.7" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LINEARLAYOUTIDGOESHERE"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2.0" >

            <TextView
                android:weight="1.0"
                android:id="@+id/headerText"
                android:layout_width="190dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btntop"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Danmarks\nJægerforbund"
                android:textColor="#D0703D"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/feedList"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/headerText"
                android:background="#d3d3d3" />

            <TextView
                android:weight="1.0"
                android:id="@+id/headerText2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/view"
                android:background="@drawable/btntop"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Jægernes\nMagasin"
                android:textColor="#454544"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/feedList"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/LINEARLAYOUTIDGOESHERE"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:fadingEdge="none"
            android:listSelector="@null" >
        </ListView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/loaidingText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Henter Nyheder..."
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Though personally I'd ditch the RelativeLayout in favor of a vertically laid out LinearLayout so you don't have to deal with "layout below" stuff.

Hope that helps!

Comment: With minor changes, this did the job. Thank you

Comment: Good to hear. Sorry it was relatively untested, so I'm happy the changes were trivial. :)